# Proving a Limit of the Pseudo-sine Function

Tags: real-analysis

I have gotten very comfortable with using the delta-epsilon definition of the limit on regular functions to prove limits but this one has me stumped:

Let $\sigma$ be the pseudo-sine function. Let $g(x) = x\sigma(\frac{1}{x})$, when $x\neq0$. Prove $\lim_{x\to 0}g(x) = 0$.

Earlier in the text, this is how the pseudo-sine function has been defined:

$f(x) = 4x(1-x), \quad 0 \le x \le 1$

$\quad \quad \quad$ $4x(1+x), \quad -1 \le x \le 0$

Extend $f$ to all of the real numbers as a periodic function $\sigma$ with period 2:

$\sigma(x + 2n) = f(x), \quad when \;x \;\epsilon \;[-1, 1] \;and\; n \;is\; an \;integer$

We will call $\sigma$ the pseudo-sine function.

Comment: $|f(x)|\le |x|\cdot 1.$

Comment: What does this mean in the context of the problem?

Comment: Sorry, $f(x)$ in my comment should have been $g(x).$